Linking 3D models (Collada) with Shapefile (point feature)
Is it possible to import 3D models in COLLADA format (.dae) into QGIS, positioning them based on a shapefile (point feature)?
Here's a brief description of the issue:
There is a 3D library of building models in .dae format, along with a shapefile (point features) that includes an attribute table containing the following parameters: the path to the .dae file, rotation, and altitude.
I'm attempting to place these buildings in the QGIS project according to the shapefile's data and export it as one .dae file.
